# Why do select Queries create additional queries to sys tables

Tags: sql-server-2016, profiler

I have an external application querying our database with an SELECT statement via Linked Server.
When I check Queries with SQL Server Profiler - I see that these queries are accompanied by an enormous load of querie to sql server internal tables/sprocs and I have no idea where these are coming from. But in the Report of top quries by total CPU time, they occupy the top 10 with millions of calls.

These are the calls:

> RPC:Completed  exec [xxx].[sys].sp_tables_info_90_rowset_64
> RPC:Completed   exec [xxx].[sys].sp_columns_100_rowset
> RPC:Completed   exec [xxx].[sys].sp_indexes_100_rowset
> RPC:Completed   exec [xxx].[sys].sp_check_constbytable_rowset
> RPC:Completed   exec [xxx].[sys].sp_table_statistics2_rowset

Is there maybe some option or flag set which enables some kind of metadata/statistcs/debug collection or check?!

Comment: These are meta-data queries generated by the client API. For a specific answer, you need to add more info to your question, such as the client API, driver and version, and a app code snippet if possible. It will be an application code or config change to avoid these queries.

Comment: Also, if these queries are coming from another SQL Server, that indicates linked server queries. Add that to your question as well.

Comment: Calls from external application are made via Linked Server (SQL Server 2016). According to supplier no options for metadata set anywhere and same configuration is also used for other linked server - and there is no problem with meta data